# weak form in Hamilton Jacobi PDE and to include an Dirichlet bound conditions

Tags: differential-equations

I tried to solve the next nonlinear PDE with **finite elements**, therefore I need to make a weak form for:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\nu(\vec{x},t) \|\nabla u\| = 0$$ and to integrate the Dirichlet condition $u=u_0$ if $x \in \partial \Omega$.

A first problem is how to define a weak for this pde.
A second problem is How I can include the Dirichlet conditions to this PDE in its weak form?

Comment: I think the question is not very clear. Perhaps you can edit it to add more context and be more precise about your problem. As written, I don't see what would go wrong if you just solved the discretized equation for $u(\vec{x}_i,t_{j+1})$ given that you know $u(\vec{x}_i,t_j)$ and $(\vec{x}_i,t_j)$ is your discretization grid. For $(\vec{x}_i,t_j)$ in $\partial \Omega$, you'll just have one less equation to solve, since you can then just set $u(\vec{x}_i,t_j)=u_0$.